# Coverage Exclusions and Source file Exclusions

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I´m using SonarQube version 6.3 and I´m trying to exclude some classes from my report, but I´m not being able to do it.

I´m in Administration -> Analysis scope and there I´m filling the Coverage Exclusions and Source file Exclusions, Both this structure

```
com.es.core.server.vertx

my-module/src/main/java/com/es/core/server/vertx/**
```

But nothing, the coverage number still the same and in the Tree view I can see those classes.

Any idea what I´m doing wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes are not immediately taken into account. A new analysis should be triggered.